# VBA Access Invalid Use of Null

Tags: vba, ms-access

Just started with Access VBA today and imagine this is a simple fix. The program calculates total guests in each service category. I must be missing something simple.

```
Public Sub CalculateTotalGuestsForEachService()

'Declare variables
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim intTotalParty As Integer

'Set the current database
Set db = CurrentDb

'Set the recordset
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select Orders.* From Orders Where ServiceID = 1")

'Cycle through the records
Do While Not rst.EOF
    intTotalParty = intTotalParty + rst!NoInParty
rst.MoveNext
Loop

'Display total amount
MsgBox "The total is " & intTotalParty

'Close the recordset
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing   

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the field `NoInParty` NULL in any of the records?

Comment: "the record is a zero"? VBA does not treat NULL values as zero, and you cannot add a NULL value to a number, it has to be a number. Check to see if it's NULL before trying to add it.

Comment: Nulls are not considered, they either are nulls or they aren't. If there is a null, you cannot add that to a number. If you want to treat your nulls as zeroes, use the [`NZ` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c). But what you should really do is `db.OpenRecordset("Select sum(NoInParty) From Orders Where ServiceID = 1")` instead of fetching all those irrelevant columns and rows and slowly adding them one by one on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any record has a *Null* value, apply *Nz*:

```
intTotalParty = intTotalParty + Nz(rst!NoInParty.Value, 0)
```

or, you could let the query sum the values:

```vb
'Set the recordset
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select Sum(NoInParty) As TotalParty From Orders Where ServiceID = 1")
If rst.RecordCount = 1 Then
    intTotalParty = Nz(rst!TotalParty.Value)
End If
```

Comment: or use `DSum` - no need to deal with a recordset